# Is checking to see if any parameters contain "__proto___" an effective way to mitigate Prototype Pollution vulnerability?

Tags: web-browser, javascript, prototype-pollution

```
    let key = keys[j] === '' ? (currentParams as any).length : keys[j];
    if (key === '__proto__') {
      throw new Error('Prototype pollution detected.');
    }
```

It at least defeats basic url-encoding, but I am unsure if it is robust enough to stop all avenues of attack.